# TortoiseSVN not asking for authentication in Windows 7 machine, works in WIndows XP

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, sharpsvn

I recently got a new Win7 machine and installed Tortoise SVN 1.9x.
I could checkout and browse the repo, when when I commit it fails saying "Error running context: An error occurred during authentication".

My >tortoise->settings->saved data->Authentication Data-Clear remains disabled and  even the all subfolders folders in Subversion\auth are empty.

I even tried looking at Windows Credential cache , found no details were stored there either.

I tried the same through Win XP machine which as TSVN 1.7x installed, I am able to commit there without any issues, it also asks for authentication box, which I do not get in Windows 7 machine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Got the same thing with one of my repositories.

Comment: No I haven't been able to figure out yet.

Comment: I got a new machine and everything works fine..Still no idea why the issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I changed my Windows Password, however I couldn't commit, browse or view log.

I couldn't find the credential anywhere in Win 10.

To fix, I created a new folder, then tried to create a new repository on that folder using the URL that was failing.

Windows then prompted me for credentials for TortProc.exe.

After entering the credentials and being able to browse again I was able to cancel the dialog and commit my other code.

Answer (score -1):

TortoiseSVN->Settings->Saved Data->Authentication Data->Clear All

worked for me..!

Comment: As I said , My >tortoise->settings->saved data->Authentication Data-Clear remains disabled ..